# What's the CLI authentication process as of Google Container Engine/Kubernetes 1.4.5?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Which steps must one currently go through in order to authenticate against Google Container Engine/Kubernetes 1.4.5?

As I set up a third Google Cloud project today, I experienced that my previous GKE cluster setup flow no longer worked. My flow was the following:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set compute/region europe-west1
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-d
gcloud config set project myproject
gcloud container clusters get-credentials staging
# An example of a typical kubectl command to see that you've got the right cluster
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Whereas this used to work perfectly, I was now getting permission errors while trying to query the cluster, e.g. `kubectl get pods` would emit the following error message: `the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get pods)`

After googling back and forth, I realized that kubectl depends on something called *Application Default Credentials*. At some point I also noticed by chance that `gcloud auth login` emits the following:

```
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help
```

So I realized eventually, that with the current gcloud/Kubernetes version I also need to call `gcloud auth application-default` in order to use the credentials of my current account rather than that of the previously activated project.

So, I am hoping someone can please clarify what is the actual authentication workflow for Google Container Engine/Kubernetes version 1.4.5??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found out the right answer. kubectl's GCP authentication plugin only supports Application Default Credentials, which were recently decoupled from gcloud's standard credentials. So, in 1.4.5 you need to run `gcloud auth application-default login` to ensure that kubectl is using the credentials you expect.

We think that most users just expect to use the same credentials as `gcloud`, with ADC being useful for some service account scenarios where `gcloud` might not even be installed. So, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/36012) to Kubernetes to add a "use `gcloud` credentials" option to the kubectl gcp authentication plugin. This should be available in kubectl 1.5.

Comment: Thanks. The current behavior is nothing short of confusing, and it was kind of lucky I was even able to piece the solution together as it was very unintuitive 

Comment: :( Sorry. We'll try to make it better. To confirm, would you expect that `kubectl`would use the exact same credentials as `gcloud`?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to do better :) Primarily, I miss a cohesive user story from GKE. From the very start I felt iffy about having to use a combination of gcloud and kubectl to work with it, as there is no well defined divide between the two. These fears were proven when this issue occurred, as it became clear that gcloud lives its own life without trying to maintain the GKE user story, i.e. it stops doing something that the latter depends on (provide ADC upon `gcloud auth login`).

Comment: Regarding your question, since I'm not a general expert on GKE/Kubernetes, and can only speak from experience with my own projects, I'm not 100% sure to what extent exactly it makes sense to operate with the same credentials for the two, but in the general case there seems to be no reason to have different credentials for kubectl and gcloud. The reason being that GKE's command line story requires a mix of gcloud and kubectl to work with the Kubernetes cluster. So you're kind of forced to deal with the separate entity of gcloud, even though it's not really relevant to what you're doing.

Comment: To sum up, I think it might be better to somehow bake the gcloud operations depended on by kubectl into itself, to free the user of the complexity of having to understand how to use gcloud in tandem with kubectl. Especially seeing as how gcloud is being developed independently of whether it might break kubectl. I don't think it's right to shift the burden of this complexity onto the user, UX is hurting from it.